# SSD failed, will cooling down recover it?

Tags: ssd, hardware-failure, hard-drive-recovery

My work laptop’s SSD failed or so tech support told me.

The laptop was very hot to the touch at the time and was being operating continuously.

Should I ask them to try it again (it has already been removed from the laptop) in case cooling down helped it, or is it gone in all probability?

Answer (score 0):

I would *assume* the tech would have tested the SSD seperately.  However, you can purchase a cheap SATA to USB converter like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000YJBL78) to attach the drive to another computer.  And you can use one of these [tools](http://mashtips.com/ssd-health-test-and-performance-monitor-tools/) to test the drive.